# DataTables get selected row tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am selecting multiple rows in a `datatable` and I can get selected rows values like this,

```
var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
  console.log(item))
});
```

but is it possible to get the selected row's jQuery row object_ printed as well? the reason I'm asking is because I have a button for each row and the button prop is not picked up when I print `item`

Also how would you remove multiple rows when I press the button?

Answer (score 0):

loop to delete multiple rows that are selected . i dont know if this is the best solution though ,

```
for(var i=0;i<selectedRowLength;i++){
 table.row($(table.rows('.selected').nodes()[0])).remove().draw()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can log the jQuery object of item like this:

```
$.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item, index) {
  console.log($('#yourTableId tbody tr:eq(' + index + ')')); 
});
```

Hope I understood the question right and it helps.

Comment: $(item) will not give me the row object. $(item) is same as printing item in this context.

Comment: This will remove the selected rows from your table with id 'yourTableId'. `$.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item, index) {
  $('#yourTableId tbody tr:eq(' + index + ')').remove(); 
});`

Comment: If you select rows 4-7, their indexes in your loop will be 0-3, so you'll remove the wrong ones